# Set a persistent env var for a user who was created without home directory

Tags: linux, debian

This is a quick one. I'm in debian, running a bash script as root. Is it possible for me to set an envar for a specific user if I have created that user without a home directory?

Looking at these answers they all refer to seeing files found in the home directory which I cannot do: 
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21598/how-do-i-set-a-user-environment-variable-permanently-not-session

Answer (score 2):

Depends a bit on the actual shell you assigned, but for instance bash will try to read `/etc/profile` before trying the individual  `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.bash_login`, and `~/.profile` files from the users home directory.

I don't have a current Debian host at hand but RHEL uses an easy drop-in directory `/etc/profile.d` for snippets as which is probably even better. E.G. something that tests for the specific UID number of your user (599) should work:

```
 # /etc/profile.d/for-user-599.sh 
 [[ $(id -u) = 599 ]] && export VAR=VALUE
```